# I'm trying switch the branch in git, but they are asking for some kind of quote

Tags: git, github

I am using MAC. I have few branches as follows,

```
origin/Andrew's-Branch
origin/HEAD->origin/main
origin/Mahmudul's-Branch
origin/main
```

I am trying to checkout `Mahmudul's-Branch`, but when I hit RETURN key the terminal is returning `<quote>` as seen below,

```
git checkout Mahmudul's-Branch
<quote>
<quote>
```

Comment: Images are fine, but not fir for all purposes. For text-heavy contents, it is better to post the text. You can format the text to make it more readable.

Comment: Note that it tends to be a bad idea to put quotes into branch names (for this very reason). It also tends to be a bad idea to mix upper and lower case (Git thinks case differences matter, but sometimes stores branch names as file names, and on your mac's file systems, the case differences probably *don't* matter.) Consider just naming the branches `andrew`, `gavin`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quote with backslash , like:

`git checkout Mahmudul\'s-Branch`

It has nothing to do with your OS.